# xmalloc error in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I am ssh'ed (via bash) to a machine on which I run the following code:

```
for i in {1..100000000}
do
  <something>
done
```

I get the error:

```
-bash: xmalloc: .././make_cmd.c:85: cannot allocate 16 bytes (7713447936 bytes allocated)
```

and it logs me out of the ssh session.

What alloc-limit is this talking about? And how do I increase it?

Comment: Do you realize how many bytes it takes to expand the `{1..100000000}` expression into a string of characters? Never mind the additional overhead for parsing to split it into a list of arguments...? I would highly suggest you find an alternate method for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using all of the memory, like 7+GB, that your process can get from free memory or you hit a limit.

The `ssh remotebox 'ulimit -a'` command will show the limits of your process - if it shows memory is 'unlimited' then you will have to add a lot swap space to increase virtual memory.  Check the ulimit manpage for more information.

Basically, your loop inside  is not letting go of memory.  It should do that if you want the loop to complete.  This is the root cause of your problem, probably not the ulimit setting.

Comment: This answer is useless. The comment below the question is the answer.

Comment: Yes it is a much better response.